# Grep lines with certain character count, including line break

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I need to grep only lines with a certain length but also **including** newline/linebreak. So the first line will be one char longer than the other one.

> Example:

```
"Random text with certain length\n"
"Random text with certain length"
EOF
```

I used grep as following:

```
grep -E "^.{length}$"
```

resulting printing both lines as they are same char count because it doesn't count the \n as char

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but try `grep -E "^.{\`wc -c\`}$"`. `^.{length}$|^.{length-1}$\n` might also be what you're looking for

Comment: [How to “grep” for line length in a given range?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184519/56041), etc.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

To me, the easiest way to get the suggested results would be to replace the newlines with sed, prior to piping to to grep (i.e. fold).  Then, unfold if necessary.

```
$ echo -e '"Random text with certain length\n"\n"Random text with certain length"\n' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"/+"/g' -e '/"+/s//"\n/g' | grep -E "^.{33}$"
"Random text with certain length"
$ echo -e '"Random text with certain length\n"\n"Random text with certain length"\n' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"/+"/g' -e '/"+/s//"\n/g' | grep -E "^.{34}$"
"Random text with certain length+"
$ echo -e '"Random text with certain length\n"\n"Random text with certain length"\n' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"/+"/g' -e '/"+/s//"\n/g' | grep -E "^.{34}$" | sed -e '/+"/s//\n"/g'
"Random text with certain length
"
```

Thanks for clarifying the description.  Some of what follows was in reference to the previous description, but seems like a waste to delete ...

I'm not sure I fully understand and made some assumptions.

1. The lines all have double quotes, or at least *something* unique to fold/unfold the newlines you want to count.
2. Either CR+LF or LF alone are what's being considered a 'newline/linebreak'
3. In the description, \n (LF/$) could mean \r (CR/^M).  That works with the reference to `wc`.  Otherwise both `grep` *and* `wc` would **not** consider the lines the same length.

In other words, as stated, by default `grep` doesn't count newline (\n) as a character but does count carriage return (\r), whereas `wc` counts both as a character.

This affirms \n = newline ($) and \r = carriage return (^M)

**\n = newline**

```
$ echo -en '\n' | wc -c
1
$ echo -en '\n' | grep -E "^.{1}" | wc -c
0
```

**\r = carriage return**

```
$ echo -en '\r' | wc -c
1
$ echo -en '\r' | grep -E "^.{1}" | wc -c
2
```

**To `grep`, carriage returns are an extra character. *Newlines are not.***

This will produce the same character count & result for both lines.

```
echo -en '\n' | sed -e '/\r/s///g' | grep -E "^.{1}" | wc -c
0
echo -en '\r' | sed -e '/\r/s///g' | grep -E "^.{1}" | wc -c
0
```

Given the criteria to filter by line length, by itself `grep -E` will never count a newline/LF as a character and therefore can't do it.  Another example where both lines are *visually* the same length, but aren't *actually* the same length ...

```
$ echo -e 'hello\r\nworld\n'
hello
world
$ cat <<< "$(echo -e 'hello\r\nworld\n' | grep -E "^.{5}$")"
world
$ cat <<< "$(echo -e 'hello\r\nworld\n' | grep -E "^.{6}$")"
hello
```

... and inserting `sed` into the pipeline, both lines are of equal length {5}:

```
$ cat <<< "$(echo -e 'hello\r\nworld\n' | sed -e '/\r/s///g' | grep -E "^.{5}$")"
hello
world
$ cat <<< "$(echo -e 'hello\r\nworld\n' | sed -e '/\r/s///g' | grep -E "^.{6}$")"
<no output>
```

Comment: So what should I use to have that one '\n' difference if grep doesn't work that way? I basically only need to get char count including \n

Comment: Now that I understand a little better, seems like you need to replace some \n but not all.  I added a TL;DR based on your output.  Maybe that's what you're trying to do?  This may be of help, too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the content save to a file named file.txt, then you can try something like this:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'length($0) > 38
```

it will output only the line with the length bigger than 38 chars:

```
"Random text with certain length\n" <br>
```

If you do:

```
cat a.txt | awk 'length($0) > 37'
```

then both lines are displayed since they all have 37 chars...

Not sure if that's what you wanted in the first place... Give it a try anyway!

Comment: This will do the same thing as grep, it doesn't count the line break as character.